# How do I remove /tree/main/ from Git repository?

Tags: github, github-pages

In my git I have the following desired path:
https://github.com/omarjuvera/Portfolios/Cybersecurity

But instead Github is giving me:
https://github.com/omarjuvera/Portfolios/tree/main/Cybersecurity

How do I remove **/tree/main/**

Comment: Why would you like to remove it? In Git, a directory maps to a tree object, and a file maps to a blob object.  `/tree/main/Cybersecurity` means the version of the directory `Cybersecurity` in the head commit of `main`. Without `/tree/main`, it is not clear if `Cybersecurity` is a file or a directory, and not clear which version of `Cybersecurity` to display.

Comment: Why do you need to "remove" parts of their URL? Unless you work at Github, that might not be possible

Comment: The file path should be `.../Portfolios/{DirectoryName}/` not `../Portfolios/tree/main/DirectoryName/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tree/main/` segment indicates that you are viewing the `main` branch of your repository. That is automatically added by GitHub and is not something you can remove or alter for the URL of the repository's web interface.

If you are looking to link directly to a file within a directory, the URL structure changes to `/blob/`. That is automatically handled by GitHub and is not something that can be manually adjusted.

If you want to present your repository content in a website-like format without the `/tree/main/`, consider using [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/). That will allow you to create a web page for your repository (at `https://USERNAME.github.io/REPO_NAME/`), which might be useful for a portfolio.

Example:

- https://alshedivat.github.io/al-folio/news/announcement_2/ (a GitHub page) actually points to:
- https://github.com/alshedivat/al-folio/blob/f6bb6b5dcb4411c539905522f928e2551e523034/_news/announcement_2.md?plain=1#L9, which is in:
- https://github.com/alshedivat/al-folio/tree/master/_news

---

So you can start looking into [GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages) and their ["Getting started" section](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site).

I like to use [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/), which has a lot of "[starter packs](https://github.com/topics/hugo-starter)".
For instance, [`zeon-studio/hugoplate`](https://github.com/zeon-studio/hugoplate) is quite complete.
Example: [`darkweak/cv-hugo`](https://github.com/darkweak/cv-hugo), which give access to pages like "[`blog/implement-traefik-into-api-platform-dockerized/`](https://devcv.fr/blog/implement-traefik-into-api-platform-dockerized/)" for the source page, in Markdown, "[`darkweak/cv-hugo/blob/master/content/blog/implement-traefik-into-api-platform-dockerized.md`](https://github.com/darkweak/cv-hugo/blob/master/content/blog/implement-traefik-into-api-platform-dockerized.md)".

The [`actions/deploy-pages`](https://github.com/actions/deploy-pages) can use one of the [starter-workflows](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/tree/main/pages) for most of the page publication frameworks you will choose (Hugo, Jekyll, Gatsby, ...).
See "[Starter Workflows](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/tree/main)".

By combining a page publication framework and a GitHub Action workflow (to build and publish those pages), you will get your Portfolio, using "nice URLs".

Comment: As you mentioned, I am looking to `"...present your repository content in a website-like format without the /tree/main/"`. Also you deducted, it is for showcasing portfolios. However since I am literally new to GitHub and learning as I go, I got into this temporary roadblock and need to figure out your recommended Github Pages option. Perhaps this can lead to an answer edit/update to include the pages route? (wink wink!, bounty, bounty)

Comment: @Omar I have edited the answer to include more information on GitHub pages.

Comment: This is VERY useful! Thanks!!! Already changed the (page section) settings of the repo and the pages are live  Lastly, how do I do what you said about "`to link directly to a file or directory without the /tree/ segment, you can use the raw content URL`" ?

Comment: @Omar That is different from GitHub pages. For instance, for the GitHub markdown source code [`darkweak/cv-hugo/blob/master/content/blog/implement-traefik-into-api-platform-dockerized.md`](https://github.com/darkweak/cv-hugo/blob/master/content/blog/implement-traefik-into-api-platform-dockerized.md), you can use the raw content with [`raw.githubusercontent.com/darkweak/cv-hugo/master/content/blog/implement-traefik-into-api-platform-dockerized.md`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/darkweak/cv-hugo/master/content/blog/implement-traefik-into-api-platform-dockerized.md).

Comment: @Omar But this is for file only, which means there is no `/tree/` in the URL anyway. I will remove that from the answer to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I remove /tree/main/ from Git repository?

You can't. Github's URL structure is:

https://github.com/<username>/<repo>/tree/<branch-or-tag>/<filepath>

Unfortunately, they don't natively support the URL structure you're looking for. And because they own the domain:

github.com

Only they could make changes to the supported paths for Github repos.

If you're looking to make the URL shorter, you can use a url shortener like [Bitly](https://bitly.com/).
If you're looking to have a vanity URL, you'll need to acquire your own domain where you have ownership over URL structure and routing decisions.